# get cookie from domain without opening this domain

Tags: java, cookies

I'm building some service in java and i foud some problem with redirections.

I have login form in domainA. After login, i want to set cookie in other domain **domainB**.

Now, when i open **domainA** after a while, i would like to check if there is Cookie sen in **domainB**, but i don't want to redirect user from **domainA** to **domainB**.

Is there any possibility, to send a request in JAVA from **domainA** to **domainB** to check if there is any Cookie?

I was trying with:

```
            try {

                URL url = new URL(rURL + "checkCookie" );
                InputStream response2 = url.openStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response2, "UTF-8"));


                for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
                    responsePool += line;
                }

            }catch(Exception e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            logger.info(responsePool);
```

and in **domainB** the code to get Cookie is just:

```
try {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie c = cookies[i];

            if (c.getName().equals("xvz")) {
                cookieSCS = c.getValue();
            }
        }

        if(cookieSCS == null || cookieSCS == ""){
            cookieSCS = "there is no cookie";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        cookieSCS = e.toString();

    }
```

But i get `java.lang.NullPointerException` and i understand that this method wont give me a cookie, but is there any possibility to get cookie from **domainB** without opening browser in **domainB** ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can read cross-domain cookies that way. Normally, such situations are handled by setting the cookie on the parent of domainA and domainB (if you have something like that).

So, if the parent is `www.example.com` and you have two domains `math.example.com` and `sci.example.com`, the cookie should be set on `.example.com` domain.

The `.` (dot) at the beginning is required in order for the cookie to be treated as a wildcard for all subdomains.